# Parse External Methods Calls Within Python Function?

Tags: python

Given the python code:

```
import sys
import os 

def MyPythonMethod(value1, value2):
    # defining some variables 
    a = 4
    myValue = 15.65
    listValues = [4, 67, 83, -23]

    # check if a file exists
    if ( os.path.exists('/home/hello/myfile.txt') ):
        pass

    # doing some operation on the list
    listValues[0] = listValues[1]       

    # check if a file exists
    print sys.path

    # looping through the values
    for i in listValues:
        print i
```

How can I extract the `names` of all external methods in function `MyPythonMethod`?

Ideally, I'd like to get a list of all external methods/members that are being invoked.

For `MyPythonMethod`, this will return:

`moduleNames = ["os", "sys"]`

`methodsInvoked = ["os.path.exists", "sys.path"]`

(yes, I know that 'path' is a member of `sys`, not a method; but I think you get the idea).

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd like to find things like `["os.path.exists", "sys.path"]`. How will you solution help in doing so?

Comment: @user540009: Are you saying the phrase "all external methods" really means "functions defined outside my code"?  Is that what you're searching for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't ever fully know what functions (and in your case we're talking about **plain functions**, not **methods**, since methods are member functions of a class), a function will call without parsing it, because it might do so dynamically and their names may depend on what is imported into the global namespace when the function gets called.

But you can see the module and function names that are referenced by a function by inspecting `MyPythonMethod.func_code.co_names`. In your case, this attribute would return the tuple `('os', 'path', 'exists', 'sys')`.

Comment: Thank you Boaz. Can you tell me what else can be retrieved using `func_code`? what other info can it give on the function?

Comment: You can try `dir(MyPythonMethod.func_code)` and see for yourself. You can get the name of the variables in the function, the consts (literals) defined in there and so on.

Comment: Great Boaz. Thanks & Shabbat Shalom!